# Robotium don't want to click on OK button into Facebook dialog

Tags: android, facebook, robotium

I'm using with Robotium test for a Facebook Connection with facebook authorization accepted.

This is my test :

```
/**
 * Test used to deconnect user
 */
public void testDeconnexion() {
    // revoque publish permissions on facebook
    FacebookManager.RevoqueAllPermissions(this.getActivity());
    // wait for authorization deleted
    solo.waitForLogMessage(this.getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.log_facebook_revoque_publish_action), 5000);
    // disconnect
    solo.clickOnMenuItem(this.getActivity().getString(R.string.menu_item_logout));
    // give it time to change activity
    solo.sleep(1000);
    // click on log out button
    solo.clickOnButton("Log out");
    // give it time to change activity
    solo.sleep(1000);
    // click on log out button
    solo.clickOnButton("Log out");
    // give it time to change activity
    solo.sleep(1000);
    // log in
    solo.clickOnButton("Log in with Facebook");
    // give it time for to see popup confirm
    solo.sleep(1000);

    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // !!!!!!! My Screenshot here !!!!!!!!!!!
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    //click on ok button
    solo.clickOnButton("OK"); // <-- Doesn't Work...

    solo.sleep(5000);
}
```

My problem is when Facebook dialog with authorization is displayed, Robotium does not want to click on "OK" button.

How to fix this?

Ty

[image: Facebook Dialog]

Comment: Robotium can't click on other apps. Is that dialog part of the Facebook app? If so that's why you can't interact with it.

Comment: It's validation test and i don't want to stay behind my phone during all testing phase. So i want to authomatize this process.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a lot of trouble using the specific "clickOn" methods. Try not specifying that it's a button you want to click by using

```
solo.clickOnText("OK")
```

instead.

Also, avoid using `solo.sleep()` because it will slow down your tests significantly even if it's not required. Make use of `solo.waitFor`-methods. For example `waitForText("text")`, `waitForActivity(YourActivity.class)` etc. Those methods return a boolean you can use in assert-statements.

See the [Solo Javadoc](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html) for the available methods.

Comment: I was able to reliably press the OK button of a screen-filling alertbox by using:
    solo.clickOnButton("OK");
or:
    solo.clickOnText("OK");
but this only worked up to a certain API level, I think it was 22. On higher levels, I had to use:
    solo.clickOnButton(2);

I tried the various suggestions found on stackoverflow, but nothing worked. In the end, I had to change the text of the button to "OK!", after which "clickOnText" worked on all API levels.